# puppeteer downlad pdf returns 503 error code

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

[image: screenshot of console tab]I am trying to download a pdf file using puppeteer but when I hit download button I receive 503 status code when I am checking network tab under inspect tool.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function simplefileDownload() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
    await page.goto(
        'https://efsa.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.2903/j.efsa.2010.1482', 
        { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }
    );

    //click accept cookie button
    await page.click('.osano-cm-accept-all.osano-cm-buttons__button.osano-cm-button.osano-cm-button--type_accept');

    //click download button
    await page.click('.grouped.right');
};

simplefileDownload();
```

### Screenshot of network tab

[image]

Comment: Could you also check if anything is being logged into the `Console` tab?

Comment: Just added another screenshot of the console tab. It seems to log some errors

Comment: This website is kinda weird, I have to keep clicking download button until download file popup show up (about 10-20 times).

Comment: Indeed it is weird site. Adds some restrictions. I manage to found this url https://efsa.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.2903/j.efsa.2010.1798 but I can't click the download button. Any solution to this?